# 3 phase induction hob, single phase wiring

Tags: three-phase, induction, appliances

While installing this 3-phase appliance I came across these diagrams which have been bugging me a bit, therefore it would be nice to find out what is the correct way to wire this up and what is the actual theory behind it.

From what I understand if I leave the wiring as it currently is (400V, 3-phase) it should be enough to connect grey with black and blue with grey so as to have 230V across both pairs, although looking at diagram one has confused me.

The question is, is my assumption correct or am I really far off?

Any suggestions or explanations will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In which country you are installing this, and is there 3-phase available, do you have a neutral wire coming at the stove, do you know if you have 400V between phases like normally in 230V countries, or 230V between phases if you don't have neutral? Do you have 25A or 16A breakers in the stove wiring? Are you asking how to wire it when you only have single phase available?

Comment: I am in Italy and I have an N, L, and G in my outlet rated 16A, wire sections 2.5 mm², between N and L is 220V.

That is correct, I am trying to understand the correct way to wire it when used in a single phase. My meter is rated 5kW and on the appliance manual is specified that the hob auto regualtes when power exceeds 3.5kW.

Comment: @floxia that's an 11kW hob, which is way more than the 5kW your meter is rated for. The 3.5kW you quoted is per-phase.

Comment: You're out of options.  Return the appliance, and get something built for single phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I called the electrician who left the jumper configuration on 400V and wired it up in single phase.

Comment: Did the electrician also tell you that your breaker will trip every time you try and use more than 1/3rd of the rated power of your hob?

Answer (score 8):

Your assumption is very far off. Please don't try to wire it yourself. You can't connect a stove requiring three phases with an outlet that provides one phase.

The stove requires three phases. The three phases need to be the three separate phases of a three-phase system, it will not work by applying one phase to all phase inputs.

It requires either three 230V phases compared to neutral and you only have one at the stove. In this case there is 400V between phases. This is normal in EU.

It can also work without neutral if there is three phase available with 230V between phases and no neutral. This is not very common in EU.

You don't have three phases available at the stove.

Also in many EU countries it would be illegal for you to wire it yourself. In most cases only legalized and competent electricians are allowed to work on fixed installations in residential buildings.

And clearly you should not attempt to wire it yourself. You need an electrician to run 3 phase wiring to stove. If your building/apartment does not have 3 phase electricity, then you need a different stove that can work with single phase electricity.

Comment: Re "You can't connect a stove requiring three phases with an outlet that provides one phase." - usually you can, just wiring all circuits parallel (they are resistive loads). Sure if stove does not include such schematics in instructions then it may be illegal, also you need quite thick wires for 11kW (about 50A on 230V).

Comment: @Arvo You can't if the stove requires 3-phase, i.e. connects  load between two phases. Apparently in this case, the stove did not really require more than 1 phase to work so it can work with single phase, but details may have been in the installation manual. You cannot determine this from the given photo.

Comment: I said "usually" :) From sticker it can be seen that (isolated) 230V loads are connected to pairs 1-3, 2-4, 1-5, there are no 400V ones - this needs to check over of course. If there were no first circuit (230V triangle) drawn, then case would be different. (And - I have yet to see household appliance, *requiring* three different phases; sure they may exist, but are not common.)

Comment: @Arvo depends on where you live geographically. Even within EU it depends. Old apartments may have 1-phase stoves. New apartments are modern and have 3 phase stoves. I don't know a single house that has only 1-phase, you simply can't get anything else than 3-phase here to a house. I also know things are different elsewhere.

Comment: In Estonia, formar USSR area. We have alot power connections as single phase.

Comment: This is an induction hob, which is not exactly a resistive load but either way the first component is typically a full bridge rectifier, so you can probably get away with one phase. Of course, you can only a fraction of the rated power before the breaker trips (best case) or your house burns down.